# Linux hardware: Apple Magic Track Pad Alternatives

Tags: linux, touchpad

I'm using Linux as my main OS for few years.

Before month or so, i tested apple magic track pad and i loved it since i am using laptop touch pad more than a mouse, it requires less movement of hand and it replaces the mouse perfectly up the point you need to draw something.

So i tried to find alternatives to it (dell or some other companies since apple production is overpriced), no luck. Any suggestions?

My problems:

- I'm not sure if that hardware will work under Linux (Ubuntu, SuSE, Fedora, Arch, etc.).
- Will Linux have full support to that device (multi-touch, gestures, etc.).
- I don't want to use unknown/low quality hardware.
- I will probably need to ship it. There fore local shop-lists won't help.

Since my *main* concern is related to working under Linux and not enough data under such devices i posted this question here.

Comment: If “magic track pad” software or hardware? If it's software, what does it do? If it's hardware, this site isn't the right place for your question: we can help with finding drivers, but not with finding the hardware (and Stack Exchange in general usually rejects shopping questions).

Comment: Where then should i ask for hardware witch would work under Linux? I won't use it under any other platform there fore i thought it would be appropriate place since my main concern that it would work under Linux.

Comment: First, you should clarify your question: make it clear that you're looking for hardware, and describe what you want that an ordinary touchpad doesn't do. On asking about hardware supported by Linux, we don't have an established policy; [I've raised the issue on our meta-discussion site](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600/hardware-recommendations-whats-the-limit).

Comment: @Gilles, Thank you. Please notify if possible on results, what in this case i should do. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some examples:

http://www.pearl.de/a-PX3640-1000.shtml?query=touch+pad

http://www.pearl.de/a-PX2569-1002.shtml?query=touch+pad

http://www.pearl.de/a-PX3206-1002.shtml?query=touch+pad

I just used this shop as an example, because I know they have budget stuff. I'm sure you can find them somewhere else as well.